# Maven Eclipse add-on missing .jar files

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I just installed Maven for a project in Eclipse. 
Now Maven is complaining that the libraries are missing for it:

[image]

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you checked if the files actually exist in your repository? It could be a permissions problem.

Comment: Would http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262186/missing-maven-dependencies-in-eclipse-project help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in your .m2 directory (use the paths which you see in the dialog above) and check whether the files are there or whether they are really missing.

If they are missing, run "mvn install" (see the "Run as..." menu) to download them.

If they exist, you've hit a bug. Try to "update dependencies" in the Maven menu.

If that doesn't help, try the latest version of m2e which you can find here: https://repository.sonatype.org/content/repositories/forge-sites/m2e/1.0.100/N/LATEST/

Comment: When I first checked they weren't there.
I left my workstation for a while and when I came back they were present. I guess they were being downloaded or propogated to the project.

Anyway, the issue is now solved