# Where is the "Maven->Update project configuration" menu item?

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse, m2e

I am having a Missing Maven dependencies in Eclipse project exactly as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4262186/1864054), and I would love to use [the solution found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4264774/1864054), but when I right-click my project in Project Explorer I can't find any such menu item:

[image]

If I right-click the project's `pom.xml`, all I see in the Maven's menu is:

[image]

Any idea what I should be doing to enable that `Update project configuration` menu option?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Righ click on the project: >Configure>Convert to Maven project

And then you can Update project configuration

Comment: Bingo! Once I did that, the scary empty `org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER` turned into a nice & full `Maven Dependencies`. I didn't even have to go through `Maven > Update Project...` to accomplish that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score -2):

try "Team" - "Commit" in Eclipse and then in a shell:

```
mvn dependecy:resolve
```