# error upgrading aspectj-maven-plugin v1.8

Tags: aspectj-maven-plugin

Upgrading the maven plugin from 1.7 to 1.8 results in the following error message:

[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.sun:tools:jar must specify an absolute path but is ${toolsjarSystemPath} @ 
    pom.xml /ash-domain line 1

Comment: I found a bug in the plugin's Maven configuration and fixed it. Cross your fingers that my [pull request](https://github.com/mojohaus/aspectj-maven-plugin/pull/19) will get into the next release.

Comment: Would you terribly mind accepting and upvoting my answer? This question is still listed as unanswered and my answer really solves the root cause of the problem, no workaround needed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same problem and I've just added in eclipse.ini the path to the JDK8. 
In my case:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin\javaw.exe
```

(must be before -vmargs)

Comment: it should be accepted as correct answer. JDK usually asks by default to install a JRE together and eclipse uses by default JRE if you don't point it on eclipse.ini to use JDK/jre.

Comment: Nut that is a path to a JRE.. no JDK

Comment: Updated the path

Answer (score 9):

I found a problem in AspectJ Maven plugin and fixed it. My [pull request](https://github.com/mojohaus/aspectj-maven-plugin/pull/19) was finally merged and is contained in the new [plugin version 1.9](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo/aspectj-maven-plugin/1.9). Just upgrade your POM and enjoy.

P.S.: The real problem is in Eclipse, but it was easier to put a workaround into the Maven plugin than to get it fixed upstream.

Comment: I verify that Mojo's AspectJ Maven Plugin version 1.9 does NOT display the described error message using Eclipse 4.6 Neon with JDK 1.8 update 101. Thanks.

Comment: upgrading to AspectJ plugin 1.9 (from 1.8) in Spring Tool Suite 3.9 fixed my issue. Thanks.

Comment: More specifically, I updated my pom as follows (changed from 1.8 to 1.10) and this worked for me:<plugin> <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>   <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId><version>1.10</version>

Answer (score 5):

I solved the problem in eclipse by adding toolsjarSystemPath as a default vm argument

Windows-->Preferences-->Java-->InstalledJREs-->EditJRE
Add default vm argument: -DtoolsjarSystemPath=%JAVA_HOME%\lib\tools.jar

Answer (score 3):

I’m ashamed to admit that in my case this error was caused by wrong JAVA_HOME path: I point it out to jre, not jdk folder

Answer (score 0):

If you're from command line, you need to have a parameter passed to the maven command with the absolute path of the `$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar`

So, the thing would end something like this:

```
mvn -DtoolsjarSystemPath=$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar clean
```

In my case even a simple **clean** was failing.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. Went to check my build path and realised its due to a lack of Maven Dependency in the library table. I follow here: [Missing Maven dependencies in Eclipse project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262186/missing-maven-dependencies-in-eclipse-project) and matter was resolved. So perhaps check if Maven is present in the build path.