# Cannot select Maven dependency from within Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have the Select Dependency Window open from within the `Maven Repositories` view in **Eclipse Mars**.

I want to be able to select from auto-populated entries when I type into the filter box. Instead, I get no search results at all:

[image: image1]

These are my Maven settings:

[image: image2]

When I select "`Rebuild Index`" against the central `Global Repository`, it hangs on **0%**.

There are a small handful of questions around this topic, but the most commonly provided answer is to check the "`Download repository index updates on startup`". 
This has not solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few things to check/know:

- You might not have properly set up proxy settings. If this is the case (which is most-likely), then it's understandable that it's not moving past `0%`.
- It might take a while to download the indexes. These are normally `150-200 MB`.

Comment: Thanks, how do I check proxy settings? I'm not using a proxy; everything I'm doing is done on a single, local machine.

Also, why can't I select dependencies from the viewer? I have to resort to adding them manually by finding them on a repository website, e.g. mvnrepository.com.

Answer (score 0):

answers already here:
[link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059685/eclipse-maven-search-dependencies-doesnt-work)
[link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262186/missing-maven-dependencies-in-eclipse-project)

else
Delete content in .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.m2e.core\nexus
Enable full index from preferences --> maven
Else there is proxy issue for you where you would need to configure settings.xml from ~/.m2/settings.xml with the necessary proxy details

Comment: Thanks, I did that and it made no difference.

I still don't know why I can't select dependencies from the viewer, and instead have to add them manually to the pom.xml.