# Getting class not found for org.json.simple.parser.ParseException even through dependecy is there in pom.xml?

Tags: java, json, xml, maven, hadoop

Here is my pom.xml

```
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
   <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.0</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

I have added the com.googlecode.json-simple as a dependency in the project, and it is working fine in eclipse build wise, but when I run the jar in hadoop I get

```
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.parser.ParseException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2134)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2099)
        at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2193)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.JobContextImpl.getMapperClass(JobContextImpl.java:186)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:745)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262186/missing-maven-dependencies-in-eclipse-project

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue could be because of the scope .

Please try to change the scope to "compile"  or  "test" . I think you are using it for testing.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am not very proficient with maven. Can you tell me where to set it?

Comment: or <scope>compile</scope> may be that should help.

Comment: with scope=test, it does not compile in eclipse?

Comment: You mean <scope>test</scope>   did you try <scope>compile</scope> for com.googlecode.json-simple

Comment: yes for test it does not compile, for compile, it compliles but gives me classNotFound?

Comment: last try you could make <scope>provided</scope>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107917/discussion-between-raghu-k-nair-and-dude).