# eclipse imported maven project cannot resolve symbols in other imported maven project

Tags: maven, import, dependencies, m2eclipse, apache-flink

I imported "flink" projects from its git clone and configured related settings. I can compile/package it successfully in command line with "mvn".

Several projects report errors that symbols cannot be resolved. For example: "MathUtils cannot be resolved  AbstractAlignedProcessingTimeWindowOperator.java    /flink-streaming-java_2.10/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/runtime/operators/windowing line 109    Java Problem".

"MathUtils" lies in project "flink-runtime_2.10" which has been compiled and packaged into a jar and its output classes folders are empty.

For project "flink-streaming-java_2.10", its "java build path"->Libraries->"Maven dependencies" includes a reference item for "flink-runtime_2.10". But it cannot resolve the symbols in "flink-runtime_2.10".

In the project group, all java projects whose builders are "java builder" and "maven proejct builder" have such problems, but projects whose builders are "scala builder" and "maven project builder", or simple "maven project builder" have no problem.

Answer (score 13):

I tried solution in: [Missing Maven dependencies in Eclipse project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262186/missing-maven-dependencies-in-eclipse-project?rq=1)

"SOLUTION: In the project that is not building correctly, right-click on the project and choose Properties, and then Maven. Uncheck the box labeled "Resolve dependencies from Workspace projects", hit Apply, and then OK. "

It works.

Comment: After I importing the project group, the default status for "Resolve dependencies form Workspace Projects" is checked for all projects. Maybe it is a bug of m2ecllipse.