# Missing maven dependencies although dependencies exist in pom.xml

Tags: java, spring, maven, dependencies, spring-framework-beans

When I add dependendencies, one of the dependency (spring-context) not exist in Maven Dependencies as given below:

[image: missing maven jars]

What I have done so far is:

> Project -> Clean  Maven ->Update Maven Project

And these steps are applied :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9761685/12100307

**pom.xml:**

```
...<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.10</version>
            <type>module</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.10</version>
            <type>module</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context  </artifactId>
            <version>5.3.10</version>
            <type>module</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>...
```

Comment: It happens to me all the time, most of the times its problems with IDE cache. I don't know how to do it in eclipse but in intellij you can simply `invalidate caches and restart`.

Comment: What is the `<type>module</type>` ? Remove that... and rebuilt on plain command..

Answer (score 0):

After some  .m2 clean, dependency clean, maven -> update project etc. reindexing etc. the problem is solved by updating pom.xml as below:

Hope helps you too!

```
... <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <spring.version>5.0.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
...
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).